# How to register a Windows sound event?

Tags: c#, windows, events, audio-player

In Windows Control Panel there is a tool that allows us to control system sounds. Visual Studio supports this by providing several "Program Events" which allow you to associate a specific sound with them.

[image: Windows Control Panel, Sound utility]

I have a console app that I would like to support these sounds configured from Control Panel. They are for several long running events in my app and usually I leave it running in the background, but I have to check that a certain operation was done before I can continue using it.

I know about `Console.Beep()`, but it doesn't suit my needs. Any suggestions on what to research? I tried looking for "C# program events" (like they are labeled in the Sound Control Panel), but obviously that gives me results about the C# `event` keyword.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/using-playsound-to-play-system-sounds

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. That link only shows how you can play a sound and links to the generic docs about registering the event in the Windows Registry, but gives absolutely no details on what registry keys to use, so this doesn't help much.

Comment: It is HKCU/AppEvents, use superuser.com if you have more questions about it.